# Java Rhino with DOM Objects

Tags: java, javascript, dom, rhino, swixml

I have a program where the user can change the layout of the user interface by editing an XML file.  I did this with a modified version of Swixml to let it include script tags and execute them.  I have Rhino included so that the user can execute Javascript events when someone clicks a button or such.  The only problem is that I want users to be able to reference the elements they include by their ids.  Is there some way to use HTML-like DOM in Rhino, like some library which already exists?

Edit: Nevermind about that function, I got it to work: EOBKAC.  But I'd still like to know if something like what I described exists.

Answer (score 0):

check out htmlunit (GUI-less DOM parser), which uses rhino javascript lib intensively.
I think working third party object with rhino may be difficult. if you have full access to source code, it may be easier because it allows you to implement get(), put(), has() inside the XML class for rhino.